# Getting a 404 Error for index.php when trying to access it externally

Tags: php, iis-7, http-status-code-404, mediawiki

After extensive search, double checking install, reinstalling, troubleshooting, I don't know where to turn next.

Background:

- I'm trying to get a wiki working using MediaWiki.
- I have PHP Manager installed for IIS 7.
- I have a MySQL server installed on the same machine.
- PHP version is 5.6.5 and installed at `C:\PHP`.

The main issue:
Locally I can view the `index.php` file, but not externally.

I get a generic `page can't be displayed` error if linking to the `/w/` directory.

Depending on the browser I'll get two results when linking to `w/index.php`:

1. `page can't be displayed`
2. `IIS 404.0 Error.`

Depending on the browser I'll get two results linking to `w/index.php?title=Main_Page;`

1. `IIS 404.0 Error`
2. `unformatted page content`

The error:

```
Module: IIS Web Core
Notification: MapRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile
Error Code: 0x80070002
Requested URL: http://localhost:80/w/index.php?title=Main_Page
Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\w\index.php
Logon Method: Anonymous
Logon User: Anonymous
```

Troubleshooting done:

- No errors shown by PHP Manager.
- Switched PHP versions (no effect).
- Externally tested other PHP forms running inside HTML (works fine).
- Checked permissions on all folders (fine).
- Edited Feature Permissions under Handler Mappings to allow executable (no change).
- Changed PHP_via_FastCGI's access restriction to execute (no change).
- Checked to make sure PHP Handling Mapping was set to `*.php` (it is).
- Checked Default Document settings and index.php. Externally tested `index.html` in `w/` (works both by direct link to file and link to folder).
- Externally tried tested `/w/index.html` with PHP `"Hello World"` inside it (blank page).

What am I doing wrong? Everything works perfectly fine run locally on the server.

Comment: Is `http://localhost:80/w/index.php?title=Main_Page` the website that you can view on your local machine, but not on other computers?

Comment: Yes, Christopher Bottoms. Because IIS has index.php set as default document, I would think it'd be just fine externally since it works internally. That's why I leaned more towards a permissions issue. Plus, the error also mentions the logon method as being anonymous. But when I switch to a specific user, I get a permissions error. I figured since I actually got a permissions error, that ruled it out permissions as the cause.

Comment: `localhost` is a special name that only applies to the machine that is being used. If I were to try to look at something on `localhost`, I would only be seeing things on my current machine.

Comment: Right. When I say I "externally tested" I mean that the user computer was pointed to the page directly. The environment is a LAN. Not only that but I have a page at the webroot which I've used to link to w/index.php. I was linking with the link <a href="/w/" target="_blank">The Wiki</a>. This of course works fine for me locally, but anyone on an external machine, it won't. Also bear in mind that the other machines can old the index.html file in the webroot and other html files in other folders. It's JUST php files they can't load.

Comment: Where does that long `Module: IIS Web Core ...` error message appear?

Comment: Within the IIS 404.0 error when hitting /w/ or /w/index.php

Comment: So that is what you see within the browser on the external computer? If so, then the `Requested URL:` should not contain `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

As Christpher says, `localhost` is a wrong in an URL to be contacted from outside: if that's what you see, you forgot to set [$wgServer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) correctly.